# Remove N occurrences of each item in a list

Tags: python, list, find-occurrences

I am trying to remove N occurrences of each item in a list using python, this is the code I am using :

```py
numbers = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
n = 2

result = []

for i in set(numbers):
    if numbers.count(i) > n:
        print(numbers.count(i) - n)
        result += [i] * (numbers.count(i) - n)

print(result) # [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

For n = 3, the result will be `[2, 3, 3, 3]`

Is there a better or one-liner way to do it?

Comment: What should happen if there is only one 1 in your input list?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Nothing, because in my code I set the value of n with least occurred item in the list, so for the example the n will have the value of 3 because the least occurred item is 1 and it occurred 3 times

Comment: What should happen if the items in the list that are the same are not contiguous?

Comment: Same behavior as if they are contiguous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) + [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

numbers = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
n = 3
res = list(chain.from_iterable([gr[n:] for _, gr in ((_, list(gr))
                                for _, gr in groupby(numbers)) if len(gr) > n]))
print(res)
```

---

```
[2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Or `list(chain.from_iterable(gr[n:] for _, [*gr] in groupby(numbers)))`

Comment: Or `list(chain.from_iterable(islice(gr, n, None) for _, gr in groupby(numbers)))`

Comment: That works. Added the list sorting to avoid the problem @mkrieger1 mentioned if the elements aren't contiguous

Answer (score 3):

```py
from collections import Counter

numbers = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
n = 2

ctr = Counter(numbers)
ctr -= dict.fromkeys(ctr, n)
result = list(ctr.elements())

print(result)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY8xDsIwDEV3n8JjIrWVKAtLJ46BWAiuiEicKnGGnoWlCxyCm3AbUlokhPQG6-v_b_3bYxjlEnia7ln6evd69jF4NME5MmIDJ7R-CFFwHzILRQDO_kQxYYeHTYUL7Q_bP47AxdsCGInlWHvUWqM_ct3h2Rpp5udXGpMqYoWsIVLKTkrM2SSz2pAjTyxJaQ0wRMuiFpNeFqxDvoPe)):

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```